# Rename Blazor Hybrid project

Tags: blazor-hybrid

I have to rename a blazor hybrid project, but did run in some issues.
Here is what I did.

- Copy the projet in a different folder to keep the original unchanged
- Open the copied project to see if it runs correctly
- Current project name

[image]

- Rename Solution and project as follows

[image]

- Replace TestServer1 to RetinesServer in the entire solution

[image]

- Close the project in Visual Studio and go to file explorer to change the name of the folder

Before
[image]
After
[image]

- Delete the bin and obj folders

[image]

- Delete the .vs folder

[image]

- Open RetinesServer.sln with Notepad and change the folder name

[image]

- Reloading the renamed project gives the following error, why?
  [image]

What did I forget?